# AWS Amplify federated redirectSignIn URL mismatch for React Native(Without Expo) PRODUCTION

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

Guys I need your help about Federated SignIn with Google, I did setup in my React Native project without Expo.I received an error:

```
Cannot read property 'redirectSignIn' of undefined
```

So I defined the redirectSignIn and redirectSignOut in oauth config but
I don't know what I need to do there, I got the Google information's but after call:

```
 await Auth.federatedSignIn({
        provider: PROVIDER.GOOGLE,
        token: {token},
      });
```

the app opens a external browser and try access an URL.
I already define the URL callback in the Google Cloud:

```
https://mydomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse
```

and Cognito:

```
myapp://app/signIn //for signIn
myapp://app/signOut //for signOut
```

but I still don't know how to configure the redirectSignIn and redirectSignOut in my app. I did it:

```
const oauth = {
  domain: `mydomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com`,
  scope: [`phone`, `email`, `openid`, `profile`],
  redirectSignIn: `myapp://app/signIn`,
  redirectSignOut: `myapp://app/signOut`,
};
```

and int he AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="app">
```

But the app still opening a external browser with error :

```
Error: redirect_url_mismatch
```

Someone have an example ?
Please.

Answer (score -1):

with amplify hosted-ui authentification, you must pass the redirectsignin url :
You can call Amplify.configure in init method of your auth component

```
           
 Amplify.configure({
                Auth: {
            
                    // REQUIRED only for Federated Authentication - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
                   // identityPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-1234-abcd-1234567890ab',
            
                    // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
                    region: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
            
                    // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Federated Identity Pool Region
                    // Required only if it's different from Amazon Cognito Region
                   // identityPoolRegion: 'XX-XXXX-X',
            
                    // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
                    userPoolId: 'eu-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            
                    // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID (26-char alphanumeric string)
                    userPoolWebClientId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            

                    oauth: {
                        domain: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                        scope: ['phone', 'email', 'profile', 'openid', 'aws.cognito.signin.user.admin'],
                        redirectSignIn: 'http://localhost:4200/home/welcome',
                        redirectSignOut: 'http://localhost:4200/login',
                        responseType: 'code' // or 'token', note that REFRESH token will only be generated when the responseType is code
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Finally i wont use aws for ionic-cordova app. The workaround is not good and AWS support din't help us.